# Magento2: What is difference between ProductFactory and CollectionFactory?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

What is the difference between this below code?

> **Class** : `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory`
>
> **Code**  : `$this->productFactory->create()->getCollection();`
>
> **Class** : `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`
>
> **Code** : `$this->collectionFactory->create();`

Answer (score 0):

Result is the same in this case.

`$this->productFactory->create()->getCollection();` will use the basic method `getCollection()` of class `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`, resulting in creating collection by object manager.

`Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` is directly responsible of creating product collection. Extra logic can be added in this class.

You should use CollectionFactory as much as you can.